# Is there any way to improve this array code?

Tags: java

This was one of the problems on App Academy Admission challenges. They weren't hard but my knowledge in java is extremely limited so it took longer than normal. The problem I had was: given an array of numbers and a target number, if the elements in the array are a multiple of the target number return them in an array format. Ex: {7, 12, 9, 5, 15}, 3 would only return 12, 9, 15

My thought process: I'll just have an empty array with equal elements as the passed in array. Create a count variable to increment the temp array. Loop and assign values. Create a new variable for the output the same type as the method and pass in everything from the temp array to the new array. Return.

I feel like there's an easier way to do this but I don't know how/what to look up.

```
    public static Integer[] multipleSelect(Integer[] nums, int target) {
        int [] temp = new int[nums.length];
        int count = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < nums.length; x++)
        {
            if(nums[x] % target == 0)
            {
                temp[count] = nums[x];
                count++;
            }
        }
        Integer[] output = new Integer[count];
        for(int y = 0; y < count; y++)
        {
            output[y] = temp[y];
        }

        return output;
    }
```

The website accepted this but I didn't like it that much. How do I improve it?

Comment: You might be better off with a [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Although note that on Code Review, you should post complete runnable examples, so supply a `main` along with this code.

Comment: You could remove the second array `output` and just reassign the `temp` array as an `Integer` array. That way you can just directly return `temp` without having to create a second array.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can improve the space complexity of the program by using an array list and when your condition satisfies you can append values to the list to improve the space complexity of the first array then if you go by the above code you can convert array list to array by

```
Integer[] output = {name of arraylist}.toArray();
```

then you can return this array from the function

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can use Java 8 or above, this is the perfect place to use a Stream, which let's you do what you want in a single line:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class X {

    public static Integer[] multipleSelect(Integer[] nums, int target) {
        return Arrays.stream(nums).filter( x -> x % target == 0).toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] input = new Integer[] {7, 12, 9, 5, 15};
        Integer[] output = multipleSelect(input, 3);
        for (Integer i : output)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
12
9
15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the second array&loop by using two incrementing values, $i for the current index of the input array, and $j for the index in the output. 
As noted above/below, you would benefit from using an arraylist or non-fixed length data type for the output.